# Multiply each value in a column by a row python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I have a small subset of data here:

```
import pandas as pd

days = [1, 2, 3]

time = [2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(days)

df2 = pd.Series(time)

df2 = df2.transpose()

df3 = df1*df2
```

Df1 is a column of data and df2 is a row of data.  I need a dataframe that is going to be 3x9 where the row is multiplied by each value in the column to make one large dataframe.
The end result should look like:

```
df3 = [2  4  2  4  2  4  2  4  2
       4  8  4  8  4  8  4  8  4
       6  12 6  12 6  12 6  12 6 ]
```

They way I currently have it for my larger dataset, only a few datapoints are correctly multiplied and most are nans.

Answer (score 2):

Dot(product) is one of the solutions to this problem

```
import pandas as pd
days = [1, 2, 3]
time = [2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(days)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(time)
# use dot 
df3 = df1.dot(df2.T)
df3
```

Output

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   2   4   2   4   2   4   2   4   2
1   4   8   4   8   4   8   4   8   4
2   6   12  6   12  6   12  6   12  6
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but I am receiving a matrices are not aligned error.  Any idea why that is? my one column dataframe does have a name if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df1.dot(df2.to_frame().T)
```

Output:

```
   0   1  2   3  4   5  6   7  8
0  2   4  2   4  2   4  2   4  2
1  4   8  4   8  4   8  4   8  4
2  6  12  6  12  6  12  6  12  6
```